# Export Dynamodb to S3 using Hive

Tags: json, hive, amazon-dynamodb, emr

I referred to this link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/EMR_Hive_Commands.html.

My hive script is like below:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS hiveTableName;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hiveTableName (item map<string,string>)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler' 
TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = "test_table", "dynamodb.region"="us-west-2");  

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS s3TableName;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE s3TableName (item map<string, string>)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
LOCATION 's3://bucket/test-hive2'; 

SET dynamodb.throughput.read.percent=0.8;   

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE s3TableName SELECT * 
FROM hiveTableName;
```

Dynamodb table can be successfully exported to S3, but the file format is not JSON, it is like:

```
uuid{"s":"db154955-8555-4b49-bf40-ee36605ac510"}num{"n":"1294"}info{"s":"qwefjdkslafjdafl"}
uuid{"s":"d9898564-2b56-42ba-9cfb-fd092e7d0b8d"}num{"n":"100"}info{"s":"qwefjdkslafjdafl"}
```

Does someone know how to export in JSON format? I know I can use Data Pipeline, and it can export dynamodb table to S3 in JSON format, but for some reason I need to use EMR. I tried another tool: https://github.com/awslabs/emr-dynamodb-connector, and use the command:

```
java -cp target/emr-dynamodb-tools-4.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.tools.DynamoDBExport /where/output/should/go my-dynamo-table-name
```

but the error was

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.tools.DynamoDBExport
```

Can someone tell me how to solve these problems? Thanks.

== update ==

If I use to_json, as Chris suggested, my code is as below:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS hiveTableName2;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hiveTableName2 (item map<string, string>)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler' 
TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = "test_table", "dynamodb.region"="us-west-2");  

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS s3TableName2;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE s3TableName2 (item string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
LOCATION 's3://backup-restore-dynamodb/hive-test'; 

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE s3TableName2 SELECT to_json(item)
FROM hiveTableName2;
```

When I look at the generated file, it's like

```
{"uuid":"{\"s\":\"db154955-8555-4b49-bf40-ee36605ac510\"}","num":"{\"n\":\"1294\"}","info":"{\"s\":\"qwefjdkslafjdafl\"}"}
```

What I want is a nested map, like

```
map<string, map<string, string>>
```

not

```
map<string, string>
```

Can someone give me some suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SELECT *` query is emitting a serialized form of the Hive `map`, which isn't guaranteed to be JSON.  You may want to consider using the [Brickhouse](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse) Hive UDF's.  In particular, calling the [`to_json`](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/wiki/Json-udfs) function would be a good fit for guaranteeing a JSON format in your output.

> - **to_json** -- Convert an arbitrary Hive structure ( list,map, named_struct ) into JSON

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE s3TableName SELECT to_json(item) 
FROM hiveTableName;
```

Comment: Thank you Chris! But I still have a problem, please refer to the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

On November 9, 2020, DynamoDB released a new feature to export your data to an S3 bucket - you can read more about it here:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-export-amazon-dynamodb-table-data-to-data-lake-amazon-s3/

It's a native, server-less solution, and currently (as of 11/20) supports DynamoDB JSON.